# Binding Time with View in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. I have a pretty basic question, for which I have tried to look for solutions in SO.

I want to show the current time (update the view every second as clock ticks) in my view and I have arrived at something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TimeCtrl">
   <b>{{getDatetime()}}</b>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function TimeCtrl($scope)
{
   $scope.getDatetime = function(){
      return(new Date().toLocaleString());
   };
}
```

I see the time in the view, except that it dosen't update itself. I need to refresh the page to see the latest time.

**Question**

1) Why dosen't my code update the time every second. Data binding is supposed to work this way?

2) I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/628cf/1/) fiddle in one of SO answers, but do not understand why we need to call `$interval`.

3) Any other ways to arrive at the solution?

**Note** : I only want to show the current Time, I do not want to show Date .

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at apply / digest in Angular http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$interval` which will run digest cycle each second, & the `getDateTime()` function will get called to update binding.

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[])

app.controller('TimeCtrl',function ($scope, $interval)
{
    $interval(function(){
        // nothing is required here, interval triggers digest automaticaly
    },1000);
   $scope.getDatetime = function(){
      return(new Date().toLocaleString());
   };
});
```

[**Working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/628cf/111/)

Comment: @Sandeep Nayak does it helped you?